# How to execute multiple rows in web service Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, ml-studio

I create a model in Azure ML studio. 
I deployed the web service.

Now, I know how to check one record at a time, but how can I load a csv file and made the algorithm go through all records ?

[image]

If I click on Batch Execution - it will ask me to create an account for Azure storage.

Is any way to execute multiple records from csv file without creating any other accounts?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way and it is simple. What you need is an excel add-in. You need not create any other account.

You can either read [Excel Add-in for Azure Machine Learning web services doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/excel-add-in-for-web-services) or you can watch [Azure ML Excel Add-in video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ju1CzDjiOMQ).

If you search for [videos on excel add in for azure ml](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=excel%20add%20in%20for%20azure%20ml&client=firefox-b-ab&dcr=0&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinqP3a_67ZAhXBr48KHdiYAXUQ_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=616), you get other useful videos too.

I hope this is the solution you are looking for.